# Saber cuantas <p> tiene un <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery

Necesito saber cuantas `<p>` tiene un `<div>`, ejemplo:

```
<div class="body">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
    <div class="paragraphs">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Solo me interesa saber la cantidad de `<p>` que tiene `<div class="body">` más no las que contengan otros `<div>`. En este caso el resultado tendría que ser 5 y no 6.

Comment: La pregunta no es tonta, Jose Darío, es muy válida. @Jose no ha criticado la pregunta en sí, sino que falten ejemplos de lo que has intentado, aunque no ha respondido de la forma más amistosa posible. Os recuerdo a ambos que Stackoverflow tiene reglas, tanto para preguntar (https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) como para responder (https://es.stackoverflow.com/conduct#unfriendly-language). Un saludo a ambos.

Comment: Si lo has sentido asi, lo siento, no era por criticar, era por pedirte algo que hubieses intentando tu ya aunque no hubiese funcionado. Es norma de la casa, aunque tambien debo pedirte disculpas por la segunda pregunta, está fuera de lugar. Lo siento, no volvera a ocurrir, como dice el rey de mi pais.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usa `document.querySelectorAll('.body > p')` para obtener todos los párrafos dentro del div con clase `body` y ahí tienes la cuenta. El `>` es para incluir solo los párrafos directos, sin él, también contaría el que está dentro de `paragraphs`:

```js
let ps = document.querySelectorAll('.body > p');
console.log(ps.length);
```

```html
<div class="body">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
    <div class="paragraphs">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¡Super! Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar con

`$('div.body').find('p').length`

EDITO

la respuesta de arriba arrojará todos los elementos `p`, si solo quieres lo de los div de body, entonces con

`$('div.body').children('p').length`

```js
console.log($('div.body').children('p').length)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="body">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
    <div class="paragraphs">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ten en cuenta que si existe otro `div` con la misma clase `body`, puede causar problemas, lo mejor sería ponerle un id

PD. La solución de Triby me parece mas adecuada dado que es js puro, de todos modos dejo esta con JQuery por si la necesitas

Comment: Al ejecutarlo da como resultado 6, lo que significa que también esta contando el del otro div, ¿a que se debe esto?

Comment: Tienes razón, disculpa leí mal la pregunta, ya la he corregido por si aun a alguien le llega a servir